# Подряд два слеша в URL

Tags: url

Влияет ли на что-нибудь, например, на индексацию в поисковиках, наличие двух подряд идущих слешей в адресе страницы?

Например, http://www.tajarea.ru//2

Comment: http://www.tajarea.ru//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////2

Та хоть 150! Смыл от этого какой?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вы пытаетесь использовать ЧПУ. Так что мешает правильно организовать ссылки?

Comment: пропишите mod rewrite

Comment: Мышь зарыта в другом месте. Дело в том, что я использую модуль один, не мной написанный, и он делает такие ссылки для пагинации. К сожалению я их убрать не могу, так как модуль пагинации один для всех разделов, оно правильно без повторных слешей идет только на главной странице, на других страницах все норм. Если убрать с главной страницы, то на других разделах вообще будет без слеша, поэтому решил не трогать. А если оно таким образом будет индексироваться, то никаких проблем!

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай это не правильная индексация. Поставить заглушку не судьба?

Comment: Лучше исправьте модуль или заставьте автора это сделать, потому что это откровенный косяк.

Comment: @ling я о том же во всех сообщениях твержу.

Comment: Ну спасибо за советы, но вопрос был в другом... и он решен.

Answer (score 1):

Да, влияет на индексацию.

- site.ru//olo
- site.ru/olo/
- site.ru/olo

Все эти ссылки для ПС будут совершенно разными.

Comment: Ну, разные. Так в карту сайта я добавлю только те, что мне надо и именно они будут проиндексированные, и уберу те, что меня не устраивают. Так что не принципиально.

Comment: Принципиально, необходимо делать защиту от такого. Так как любой сможет дать вот такую ссылку site.ru//olo на ваш сайт, и ПС её поиндексируют, а ПС не любят одинаковые страницы. 301 редирект нужен.

Answer (score 1):

По идее поисковику побарабану, контент по этой ссылке он получит и проиндексирует, но точно покажет только практика

Comment: Посмотрим что получится...